# Assigning 'setTimeout' to 'variable.oniput'

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a function that will run after 1 second when the text in the input field has changed.

This works:

```
var foo = document.querySelector("#input");
foo.oninput = theWrapper;
function theWrapper() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myFunction();
    }, 1000);
}
```

But this doesn't, why?

```
var foo = document.querySelector("#input");
foo.oninput = setTimeout(function() {
    myFunction();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: BTW, `function() { myFunction(); }` is equivalent to just `myFunction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct translation will be

```
var foo = document.querySelector("#input");
foo.oninput = function(){ setTimeout(function() {
    myFunction();
}, 1000)
};
```

`oninput` should be a function but what you are assigning is a Number, representing the ID value of the timer that is set.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` doesn't return  a function, it returns a cleartimerid.

```
foo.oninput = setTimeout(function() {
    myFunction();
}, 1000);
```

here , your assigning that cleartimeoutid to `oninput`.

use

```
foo.oninput = function(){ 
  setTimeout(function() {
    myFunction();
   }, 1000)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because

```
setTimeout(...)
```

is not a function it is clear timer id because the function already returned. So to make it a function wrap it in a anonymous function.

```
foo.oniput = (function(){ setTimeout(...); });
```